# SQLPackage Revoking and Granting Permission on Database Roles

Tags: sql-server, permissions

### The Behavior

I am using Visual Studio SQL database projects to source control our azure SQL DB's.  As part of the project definition, we have database roles which are managed.

When the project is applied to the target azure SQL database, for roles which grant permissions to objects such as tables and procedures the permissions are being revoked, the changes to the database objects applied then the permissions are being granted again by the project even if the object the permissions are granted to does not change.

This only affects roles where the permissions are defined on objects and not on schemas.

For example when deploying the project this role will have the permissions revoked and granted again:

```
CREATE ROLE [myDbRole]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
GO 

GRANT INSERT ON [mySchema].[tableA] TO [myDbRole]
GO
```

However if the role is defined as having permissions at the schema level rather than the object level this does not happen:

```
CREATE ROLE [myDbRole]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
GO 

GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA::[mySchema] TO [myDbRole]
GO
```

I can't see any switches for the SQLPackage.exe that would prevent this behaviour other than excluding roles entirely from the project deployment, which is not what I would like to achieve.

---

### The Real Problem

The reason we care is that we are releasing small incremental changes all the time to the DB's, during the period the deployments are being run the permissions being revoked causes issues as the applications that require the permissions can no longer function correctly.

Comment: You've described the behavior of the project deployment, but not a problem with it.

Comment: Could you configure an audit on SQL Server to capture object and permission changes so that you can see what's going on each time you apply the project changes?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @HardCode sorry I wasn't explicit enough in the post, how can I prevent this behaviour?  If the objects are not changing that the role has specific permissions granted to and the role is not changing, how can I prevent the granted object level permissions being revoked and then re-granted on each and every deployment?

Comment: @Ronaldo, I can see exactly what is going on without needing to review the audit logs (although I can also see those statements being ran in the audit) as when SQL package is being executed I have set the switch:
/DiagnosticsFile:$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/output.log.

Comment: This switch captures all t-SQL statements the deployment performs to a log file and I can see it performing the revoke's first, then applying any DDL changes to the target db to match the desired state defined in the project, then it re-grants the revoked permissions.

Comment: If I understood correctly, at the end of the process all permissions are ok (they were revoked and then granted again) and no permission was lost at the process. Why do you care if the engine chooses to do it that way? What problem does it cause?

Comment: @Ronaldo,  the reason we care is that we are releasing small incremental changes all the time to the DB's, during the period the deployments are being run the permissions being revoked causes issues as the applications that require the permissions can no longer function correctly.

Comment: Now I see. I think that answers @HardCode comment too.